# Creating installer package from GeoServer source?

Tags: geoserver, installation

I have a project which required to develop by Geoserver Source (clone from GitHub).

Now, i have done my project and i want to create the installer from my project (such as in Visual Studio you can create setup package from your solution by adding new install wizard to create setup file...).

I do not know where to start.

Can anyone help me, or show me any thread, forum that discuss about it.

Comment: It might help to say how your project relates to GeoServer, and what you are trying to achieve in terms of an outcome (as opposed to a process). Are you familiar with building installers for windows? Can you just chain the existing .exe installer? Please edit the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays GeoServer releases are automated in our build server and the instructions do not get into the details of building an installer, but this old guide from the times when things were done by hand might provide you instructions on how to get an installer done:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver-history/blob/master/doc/en/developer/source/release-guide/index.rst